# get Font Size in Python with Tesseract and Pyocr

Tags: python, tesseract, font-size, python-tesseract

Is it possible to get font size from an image using `pyocr` or `Tesseract`?
Below is my code.

```
tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
tool = tools[0]
txt = tool.image_to_string(
      Imagee.open(io.BytesIO(req_image)),
      lang=lang,
      builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
)
```

Here i get text from image using function `image_to_string` . And now, my question is, if i can get `font-size`(number) too of my text.

Comment: Try amending your sample code to be [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr), you can get a `ResultIterator` after calling `Recognize` on your image, for which you can call the `WordFontAttributes` method to get the information you need. Read the method's documentation for more info.

```
import io
import tesserocr
from PIL import Image

with tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(req_image))
    api.SetImage(image)
    api.Recognize()  # required to get result from the next line
    iterator = api.GetIterator()
    print iterator.WordFontAttributes()
```

Example output:

```
{'bold': False,
 'font_id': 283,
 'font_name': u'Times_New_Roman',
 'italic': False,
 'monospace': False,
 'pointsize': 9,
 'serif': True,
 'smallcaps': False,
 'underlined': False}
```

Comment: It looks like this no longer works, sadly :/ https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1074

Comment: Though this is old, the method only works in Tesseract 3.0.5