# Calculate / extract font size in images

Tags: python, image, fonts, size, font-size

I would like to extract the font size of strings in images.

Here is an example image:

[image: Example image]

Output should be for example:

"Percentage of total music sales by method" -> 12pt

"Streams" -> 10pt

How can I achieve this?

tesserocr seemed to have provided something like this, but is no longer supported / provided, see:

[get Font Size in Python with Tesseract and Pyocr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324626/get-font-size-in-python-with-tesseract-and-pyocr)

Cheers

Comment: do you deal with jpeg images as input?

Comment: yes jpeg and png

Comment: You may want to start with "how do I detect regions of text in images" first, before you worry about figuring out how many lines there are and what that means in terms of x-height and baseline spacing. (and of course: that's something to google/search SO for, image analysis using opencv is kind of the gold standard in this case and there are plenty of tutorials that teach you how to use it)